# Method dispatching in R based on presence of specific parameters

Tags: r

I have two function, `f1(...)` and `f2(...)`.  I would like to group them under a single function `f(...)` and conditionally pass the parameters of `f(...)` to either `f1` or `f2`.  If `f(...)` is passed a parameter called `special.param`, then I will call `f2(...)`.  Otherwise I will call `f1(...)`.  I don't believe `UseMethod` can handle this since it will check for the class of the first parameter rather than the presence of a certain parameter.  What is the correct way to do this?  Is there a way to check the names of the parameters in `...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are your functions and `p` is your special parameter

```
f1 <- function(..., p) "f1"
f2 <- function(..., p) "f2"
```

In S4 (maybe that's not what you're looking for...) you could write a generic that dispatches on the special parameter

```
setGeneric("f", function(..., p) standardGeneric("f"),
    signature="p", useAsDefault=f1)
```

and implement a method that is invoked when the parameter is missing

```
setMethod("f", "missing", f2)
```

A more symmetric implementation with the same consequence would be

```
setGeneric("f", function(..., p) standardGeneric("f"), signature="p")
setMethod("f", "ANY", f1)
setMethod("f", "missing", f2)
```

with

```
> f(p=1)
[1] "f1"
> f()
[1] "f2"
```

A simpler base R alternative (implied by a comment and deleted answer) is

```
f <- function(..., p) {
    if (missing(p))
        f2(...)
    else
        f1(..., p=p)
}
```

This would become tedious and error prone if there were more than two alternatives for p (e.g., missing vs. numeric vs. logical) or if dispatch were on more than 1 argument f(x, ..., p). The S4 approach also means that available methods are discoverable (`showMethods(f)`) but carry additional documentation and NAMESPACE burdens when implemented in a package.

Comment: Is there advantage to this over simply creating a function `f` that calls `f2` if `missing(p)` and `f1` otherwise?  Your way seems more R-like to me, but I'm wondering if there's a practical difference.

Comment: @andrew I added a paragraph at the end that highlights some pros and cons.